# On the Generalization of Totally Positive Matricies to Minors of size dependent sign

Tags: linear-algebra

A matrix is called totally positive (nonnegative) if $\forall k$, every $k$ by $k$ submatrix has positive (nonnegative) determinant. In other words, all minors are positve (nonnegative).

For my application, I merely need all minors of a given size to have constant sign. Formally, there exists $\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2,\ldots \in\{-1,1\}$ such that $\forall k$ for all $k$ by $k$ submatricies $A_k$, $\epsilon_k det(A_k) \geq 0$.

Totally positive matricies take $\epsilon_k=1$ for all $k$. Multiplying each entry by negative constant yields a matrix with $\epsilon_k=(-1)^k$.

My question is: do other examples of matricies with size determined minor sign exist and have they been studied?